# Convert arrays (of numpy data types) to tuples (of native data types) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures, tuples

How can effectively I convert an array of arrays of `numpy.float64` to tuple of tuples of `float`

Input is

```
a = array([array([1.]), array([2, 3]), array(['a', 'b', 'c'])])
```

where values are of `numpy` basic types, such as `numpy.float64`, `numpy.int32`, `numpy.str_`, etc.

Output is

```
((1.,), (2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

where values are of native type `float`, `int`, `str`, ...

I suppose there may be recursive and iterative approaches... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a numpy array of arrays of different sizes and types is usually a sign something's gone wrong in your design.  But if you've got that for some reason, you can use `.tolist()` to convert a numpy array to a list and simultaneously change the types to Python-native ones.  For example:

```
>>> a = array([array([1.]), array([2, 3]), array(['a', 'b', 'c'])])
>>> a
array([array([ 1.]), array([2, 3]),
       array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
>>> t = tuple(tuple(x.tolist()) for x in a)
>>> t
((1.0,), (2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

where we had

```
>>> [type(x[0]) for x in a]
[<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.int32'>, <class 'numpy.str_'>]
```

but now have

```
>>> [type(x[0]) for x in t]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>]
```

Comment: Thanks! nice and clean!

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension does the job nicely:

```
In [191]: a = np.array([np.array([1.]), np.array([2, 3]), np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])])
In [192]: a
Out[192]: 
array([array([ 1.]), array([2, 3]),
       array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
In [193]: [tuple(i) for i in a]
Out[193]: [(1.0,), (2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
In [194]: tuple([tuple(i) for i in a])
Out[194]: ((1.0,), (2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c))
```

Wrapping the list of arrays in another array layer doesn't do much.  An array of dtype object is just a list with a `ndarray` wrapper.  Most operations of `a` will treat it like a list.

```
In [195]: ll=[np.array([1.]), np.array([2, 3]), np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])]In [196]: ll
Out[196]: 
[array([ 1.]), array([2, 3]), array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
       dtype='<U1')]
In [197]: [tuple(l) for l in ll]
Out[197]: [(1.0,), (2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

---

correction - we need to use `tolist()` first if we want to convert the elements of the inner arrays.  `tuple(i)` is like `list(i)`, iterating on the 1st dimension, while `i.tolist()` does a recursive conversion.

```
In [204]: type([tuple(i.tolist()) for i in a][0][0])
Out[204]: float
```

---

More on the difference between `list` and `tolist` when we apply them to a 2d array:

```
In [210]: np.ones((2,3)).tolist()
Out[210]: [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
In [211]: list(np.ones((2,3)))
Out[211]: [array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])]
In [212]: tuple(np.ones((2,3)))
Out[212]: (array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]))
```

There isn't a `totuple()` method, and nothing quick and easy that would convert a nested lists of lists to a nested tuple of tuples.

`tolist` does not recurse through the `dtype=object` layer:

```
In [214]: a.tolist()
Out[214]: 
[array([ 1.]), array([2, 3]), array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
       dtype='<U1')]
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `numpy` basic data structures persist. For example, `type(tuple([tuple(i) for i in a])[0][0])` yields `numpy.float64`, but needs to be `float` (just native data type).

Comment: I forgot that there's a difference beteen `list(a)` and `a.tolist()`.  The latter is a recursive converter.  Try my edit.

Comment: I didn''t notice your answer when I made my additions.